# Adding up currency values

Tags: php, currency

I'm trying to add up some currency using PHP.

The values I'm trying to add up are like this:

- 2.500
- 10,50
- 20,70
- 15
- 75

The first one is 2 thousand euro's, the second one is 10 euro's and 50 cents.

I want to add these up so it comes up to a total of 2621,20 euro's (if I calculated it correctly).

I tried passing the values to floats but that didn't give me the result I expected.
Here is what I have made so far:

```
$rent = $product->get_price_html();
$rent_int = (int) preg_replace('|[^0-9]|i', '', $rent);

// I'm working in wordpress, but the values are the same as the above ones

$gwl = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'g/w/l_prijs', true);
$tti = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 't/t/i_prijs', true);
$heffing = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'heffingen_prijs', true);
$verzekering = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'verzekering_prijs', true);

$total = (float)$rent_int + (float)$gwl + (float)$tti + (float)$heffing + (float)$verzekering;
```

As you can see I'm removing everything that's not a number from the rent value. Ofcourse this causes a major issue when the rent value is a float and not an int.

How would I go about calculating currency properly?
I'm not sure how it's done in other countries, but the dot represents 1000 and a comma is the cents.

Comment: are the formats at least consistent, so you'd never get `2.500 = two thousand five hundred` as well as `2.500 = two euro 50 cents`? If you do, then there's essentially NO way of translating this reliably, because you can't have the exact same string representing two totally different values.

Comment: Cents are always depicted as `2,50`, not `2.50`. `2.50` won't occur, but `2.500` can (and is).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using Woocommerce.

If I am not mistaken if you should be able to do:

```
$rent = $product->get_price();
```

And then get rid of all of that preg_replace non-sense.

This should set $rent to a floating point value that you can do your maths on.

http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#752-759

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use the comma as a decimal then you can't strip it out.

Try this line instead of your current line to get the `$rent_int` value

```
$rent_int = (float) str_replace(',','.',preg_replace('|[^0-9,]|i', '', $rent));
```

Obviously this is no longer an int (its a float) but I leave tidying up your variable names to you.